# Android - which Activity methods require a super constructor?

Tags: android, methods, constructor, overriding, super

In most Android apps, `onCreate()` is overridden with the first bit of code being `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` and I know this gathers the savedInstanceState Bundle and is neccessary for compilation but what about all of the constructors?

`onResume()`, `onStop()`, `onStop()` etc. Which overridden methods have important super constructors you need to include?

Is there a list somewhere?

I see the super constructors included in some code, not in others.. I have included them sometimes myself, others not and have never really noticed a difference..

Any light that could be shed would be well received!

Cheers

Comment: You're misusing the term *constructor* here.  A *constructor* is a special method that creates a new object.

Comment: Are you saying the first defalt method inside each of those method which often pass parameters ie. `super(savedInstanceState)` in onCreate are not cases of a parameter being passed to the constructor of the parent class? That they are just methods?

Comment: Yes.  Inside `onCreate()`, when you call `super.onCreate()`, you are not calling the activity's *constructor*.  You are calling `onCreate()`, which is a *method*.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, good to know your specifics!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onCreate()`, `onStart()` and `onResume()` are used to startup the activity while on `onStop()` and `onDestroy()` are used to stop or clean up the activity.

As per the documentation you need to call the super for each of the method.

> Derived classes must call through to the super class's implementation
>   of this method. If  they do not, an exception will be thrown.

For [more info](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onStop%28%29)

Comment: That last line is essentially what I was looking for, cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Check this [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

The entire lifecycle of an activity is defined by the following Activity methods. All of these are hooks that you can override to do appropriate work when the activity changes state. All activities will implement onCreate(Bundle) to do their initial setup; many will also implement onPause() to commit changes to data and otherwise prepare to stop interacting with the user. You should always call up to your superclass when implementing these methods.

```
public class Activity extends ApplicationContext {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState);

    protected void onStart();

    protected void onRestart();

    protected void onResume();

    protected void onPause();

    protected void onStop();

    protected void onDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you read the source code, you'll notice how in `Activity.java` those 6 methods have code inside, so I'd say you should call super for every overriden `onXXX` method.